# Is there a way to get details on a HITType given the HITTypeId?

Tags: mechanicalturk

I'm looking to get details on a HITType in Amazon Mechanical Turk, specifically the parameter values used when it was created. Is there an API call or a command line tool command that will let me see the things like the title, description, reward, assignment duration, keywords, auto approval delay, and qualification requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been discussed [on the developer forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=96021). The answer from AWS was that there is no way to do this, but they'll think about adding it...maybe...sometime...probably never, though.

Comment: FYI to anyone else that may have this issue - someone notes on the developer forum that you can see these values from the GetHIT operation.

Comment: Yes, you just have to know a HITId associated with the HITTypeId you're going for. And HITIds expire.

Comment: I'd check Amazon's library of CLI tools to see what they have for Mechanical Turk.